# Cancelable Collection

Tags: c#, observablecollection, bindinglist

I'm trying to implement a collection class (either derived from `ObservableCollection` or `BindingList`) that will allow me to cancel the addition of any new item as it happens.

Now I know `ObservableCollection` does not allow the editing of items in the collection during the `CollectionChanged` event for a reason but I'm looking for a way to 'bypass' this either by deriving from `ObservableCollection` or `BindingList`.

Any examples will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you would need some `BeforeCollectionChanged` event, pass an `EventArgs` with a `Cancelled` property which you look at to determine whether to add it or not.

Kinda like this, I guess:

```
public override void Add(T item) {
  var e = new BeforeCollectionChangedEventArgs();
  RaiseBeforeCollectionChanged(e);
  if (!e.Canceled)
    base.Add(item);
}
```

`CollectionChanged` is obviously too late because by then the collection already *has* been changed.